# Change “possible duplicate” text to encourage searching?

Tags: feature-request, search, duplicate-questions

Hello! I thought it would be a good idea to change the autogenerated “possible duplicate” comment to encourage searching, something like:

> Please use the search function before you ask, this was already `[asked before](url)`.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with this is the user might have searched but did not find the duplicate because they were searching a slightly different term.

I would recommend leaving the text as is.

Comment: Absolutely, it should be more generic.